# How can I implement region filling(Conditional Dilation) algorithm with matlab?

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab

How can I implement region filling(Conditional Dilation) algorithm that The algorithm terminates at step `k` if `Xk=Xk-1 with` matlab!
Fill this image with region filling algorithm in matlab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`imfill`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) function from the Image Processing toolbox.
You can either specify the points where to start the filling, or use the `'holes'` option to fill all holes:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkHkg.png');
I = I>0;               % convert to binary image
J = imfill(I,'holes');
```

--

If you want to implement the algorithm yourself, then please specify what algorithm you are using, add the code you have and tell us exactly what problems you are having. Nobody here will write the code for you from scratch, but we are glad to help with problems.